# Convert datetime object into specific string Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a date in the format `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm`, for example 31.01.2014 11:24. How can I obtain, in javascript, the string "/Date(1391160281569)/"?

Comment: So you want to convert from `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm` to `"/Date(1391160281569)/"` using javascript?

Comment: is `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm` a string dataType? or `Date` object?

Comment: A string, but i can easily obtain a date, it that facilitates the work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach

```
var date = "31.01.2014 11:24";
var sp1 = date.split(/[:. ]/);
var newDate = new Date(sp1[2], (+sp1[1] - 1), sp1[0], sp1[3], sp1[4]);
var milliSeconds = newDate.getTime();
var urFormat = "/Date(" + milliSeconds + ")/";
alert(urFormat)
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/7ZYYh/1/)

Comment: You can use `split` with regular expressions. `date.split(/[:. ]/)` would give you `["31", "01", "2014", "11", "24"]`

Comment: @tewathia Thanks, I didn't know about it.  I have included in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I took me a while but i got this:

```
var theStringVersion = "/Date("+$.now()+")/";
```

Of course, for a real date, i would have to get the timestamp for it.